# Смена verbose_name для is_superuser Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Есть кастомная модель пользователя

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Поле `is_superuser` наследуется из `PermissionsMixin`. Есть ли возможность для него заменить `verbose_name` и `help_text` на свой текст без правки исходников самой джанги?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил ответ на английском SO ([вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462144/change-verbose-name-for-is-superuser-django/36464717#36464717) на английском):

Можно наследовать `UserChangeForm` и там переопределить соответствующие поля:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    is_superuser = forms.BooleanField(label='My Verbose', help_text='My Help Text', initial=False, required=False)
```

admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
```